# Coinbase Websocket, signature in authentication

Tags: coinbase-api

How should the signature parameter be generated for opening an authenticated connection to Coinbase Websocket?  I can't find any concise description anywhere.

For `GET/PUT` API calls, I successfully generated it with the below code, but with the Websocket there is neither a "method" nor a "path_url", so what should contain the "message"?

```
timestamp = str(time.time())
message = timestamp + request.method + request.path_url + (request.body or '')
hmac_key = base64.b64decode(self.secret_key)
signature = hmac.new(hmac_key, message.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)
signature_b64 = base64.b64encode(signature.digest())
```

Comment: Having same problem here. Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution and unfortunately I got no answer to my question.

Comment: Found the solution. Please see my posted answer.

Answer (score 6):

I was finally able to solve this problem. Granted the code doesn't look all that interesting.

I'm using the following in conjunction with the [CCXT](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt) library. More specifically, the Websockets fork implementation [here](https://github.com/lfern/ccxt/blob/feature/websockets-multiple/WEBSOCKETS.md).

```
const id = this.marketId (symbol)
const timestamp = Date.now() / 1000

const p_passphrase = this.safeValue(params, 'password')
const p_apiKey = this.safeValue(params, 'apiKey')
const p_secret = this.safeValue(params, 'secret')

const what = timestamp + 'GET' + '/users/self/verify'
const key = Buffer.from(p_secret, 'base64')
const hmac = require('crypto').createHmac('sha256', key)
const signature = hmac.update(what).digest('base64')

this.websocketSendJson({
  'type': 'subscribe',
  'product_ids': [id],
  'channels': ['user'],

  'key': p_apiKey,
  'signature': signature,
  'timestamp': timestamp,
  'passphrase': p_passphrase,
})
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: this helped SO much! Finally that's what the totally unclear passage from the doc meant: `To authenticate, send a subscribe message as usual, and pass in fields to GET /users/self/verify, just as if you were signing a request` - what it meant was sign a completely unrelated string, unlike in Advanced Trade API where you sign a string that's directly related! Thanks!!